Does Elastic Search have an equivalent to SQL Group By aggregation?
I know Elastic Search could do aggregation, but you know DB aggregation is not totally same as ES world.
Like we do below in DB:
select a, b, c, d, sum(e), sum(f)
from some_table nolock
group by a, b, c, d

It will return:
a, b, c, d, sum e, sum f
1, 2, 3, 4, 100  , 100
1, 2, 3, 5, 150  , 150
...

So each a+b+c+d as different key, will have one row return.
But how can I do it in ES aggregation? It will return nested result and if I aggregation with different sequence, like a->b->c->d result will be different with d->c->b->a result. But in DB, group by a,b,c,d will not different with group by d,c,b,a.
Any suggestion is welcome, Thanks
Have tried xpack and parallelly aggregation, xpack hard to use, parallelly not as expected

A question about why the results you got from parallelly didn't match your expectations might be a bit more concrete / straightforward to answer, since that's a place where you'd be able to show code, the actual output of that code, and the expected output of that code.

(since the aggregations you show are sum()s, and sum is commutative, I also don't know what you mean when you say that ordering is changing your output; a concrete example of specific data for which incorrect results are possible might be a further way to do some good in better grounding this question to make sure it's properly understood).

sorry for the brief description, I want to show code here but too many key or sensitive word need to replace before sharing, I think composite aggregation was what I need, thanks anyway, have a good day @CharlesDuffy

First of all there is really no difference between a->b->c->d and d->c->b->a result as long as you process the keys correctly, the only difference will be the order. Here is an example:
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "b": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "c": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "d": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "e": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "f": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}


POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 4}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 5}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }

POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "a": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "a"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "b"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "c": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "c"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "d": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "d"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "sum_e": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "e"
                      }
                    },
                    "sum_f": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "f"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "d": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "b"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "c": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "c"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "a": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "a"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "sum_e": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "e"
                      }
                    },
                    "sum_f": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "f"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


However, you might be more comfortable with composite aggregations that will produce flatter results closer to what you expect from SQL.
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_groups": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "a": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "a"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "b": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "b"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "c": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "c"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "d": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "d"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_e": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "e"
          }
        },
        "sum_f": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "f"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But you can also allow Elasticsearch to write that aggregation for you and get exactly what you expected:
POST /_sql?format=csv
{
  "query": "SELECT a, b, c, d, sum(e), sum(f) FROM test GROUP BY a, b, c, d",
  "fetch_size": 10
}


I think composite aggregations is same as DB behavior, many thanks @imotov

although I can run composite aggregation, but looks like it only do aggregation on 10 records, how to do aggregation on the whole index and return complete result?
meanwhile I found someone said it not recommend to do aggregation on big index as cache limit, and we need to use scroll API to fetch all data and do aggregation in local server. That's really confused me, actually why I want to do aggregation in ES is scroll API is too slow when query big index with lot of documents. Any suggestion is welcome@imotov

Your question involves several complexities and even scratching the surface on these would exceed the 600-character limit of stackoverflow comments. You can paginate composite aggregations as outlined in the official documentation. For faster results, if your nodes have sufficient memory, consider fetching more records at once, possibly nearing the search.max_bucket limit, rather than just 10. This is controlled by the size parameter in the composite aggs.

@imotov, your SQL query is a very interesting solution

Introduction
There are three ways else for following updated documents
POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 4}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"index": {"_id": 5}}
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 5, "e": 50, "f": 50 }
{"create": {"_id":6}}
{"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "e": 50, "f": 50 }

Way #1. The multi_terms aggregation for the same mapping with pagination
Query
    GET /test/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_a_b_c_d_fields.buckets.key_as_string,aggregations.by_a_b_c_d_fields.buckets.sum_e,aggregations.by_a_b_c_d_fields.buckets.sum_f
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_a_b_c_d_fields": {
            "multi_terms": {
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "field": "a"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "b"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "c"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "d"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sum_e": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "e"
                    }
                },
                "sum_f": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "f"
                    }
                },
                "pagination": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "from": 1,
                        "size": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
    {
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_a_b_c_d_fields" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key_as_string" : "1|2|3|4",
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string" : "4|3|2|1",
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 50.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 50.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Way #2. A runtime field for the same mapping and original documents
Query
GET /test/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "compound_key": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "script": """
                String[] fieldNames = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
                List fieldValues = new LinkedList();
                int fieldNamesLength = fieldNames.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldNamesLength; i++) {
                    String fieldName = fieldNames[i];
                    if (params._source.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                        long fieldValue = params._source[fieldName];
                        fieldValues.add(Long.toString(fieldValue));
                    }
                }
                String compoundKey = String.join(" ", fieldValues);
                emit(compoundKey);
            """
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_compound_key": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "compound_key"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sum_e": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "e"
                    }
                },
                "sum_f": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "f"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_compound_key" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "1 2 3 5",
                    "doc_count" : 3,
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 150.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 150.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "1 2 3 4",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Way #3. A compound key, update_by_query, and a simple terms aggregation
New mapping
PUT /test
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "a": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "b": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "c": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "d": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "e": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "f": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "compound_key": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}

update_by_query
POST /test/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": """
                String[] fieldNames = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
                List fieldValues = new LinkedList();
                for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
                    if (ctx._source.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                        long fieldValue = ctx._source[fieldName];
                        fieldValues.add(Long.toString(fieldValue));
                    }
                }
                String compoundKey = String.join(" ", fieldValues);
                ctx._source.compound_key = compoundKey;
        """,
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}

Query with pagination
GET /test/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_compound_key": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "compound_key"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sum_e": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "e"
                    }
                },
                "sum_f": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "f"
                    }
                },
                "pagination": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_compound_key" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "1 2 3 5",
                    "doc_count" : 3,
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 150.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 150.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "1 2 3 4",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 100.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "4 3 2 1",
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "sum_f" : {
                        "value" : 50.0
                    },
                    "sum_e" : {
                        "value" : 50.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


Multi-term is an excellent suggestion if you don't need paging! Way# 2 works but it bypasses several optimization that elasticsearch would be able to apply in composite and multi-term cases, so it would be slower on a large index. The Way #3 doesn't work - it will generate the same key "1 2 3 4" for both a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 and a=4, b=2, c=3, d=1.

@imotov, thanks for your comment. I've corrected the ways
